# Python 2.7 xpath?

Tags: python, xpath

I was using xpath in python 2.4 and it was working fine.

But when I switch to python 2.7 and try to import the xpath library, it complains xpath doesn't exist:

```
from xml import xpath
```

Does anyone know if xpath exist in python 2.7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use xpath with python 2.7, [`xml.etree.elementTree`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is part of the standard library since Python 2.5 and it contains a basic xpath findall function. [PyXML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyxml/files/) is outdated and shouldn't be used.

If you need something more powerful, I would install [lxml](http://lxml.de/).